# Lock keys in DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, keypress

I don't have any idea on how to lock key when inputting on a cell in datagridview. It's like when the user already inputted 2 characters, the user should not be able to input anything on a cell. Just like putting a limit on how many characters are allowed to be inputted on a textbox. Can anyone show me how can I do this? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [MaxInputLength](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewtextboxcolumn.maxinputlength(v=vs.110).aspx) property of `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` to set the maximum number of characters that can be entered into the text box.

This has no effect on the length of text set using the `Value` property of the cell or using the `Paste` context menu. See the MSDN link for more details.